# how to use the insertText method in ngx-ckeditor angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using angular 8 in my project and I'm trying to implement **ngx-CKEditor**. I need to add custom text in the editor this should happen When I click the list I need to add the content inside the CKEditor.

i tried with this code but not working for me.

```
<ck-editor name="editor" #myEditor [(ngModel)]="editorValue" skin="moono-lisa" language="en" [fullPage]="true"></ck-editor>

<ul>
        <li (click)="selectText('adasdasd1')">adasdasd1</li>
        <li (click)="selectText('adasdasd2')">adasdasd2</li>
    </ul>
```

In ts file

```
public editorValue;
@ViewChild("editor", { static: true }) myEditor: any;
```

click event in ts file

```
selectText(value) {
    this.myEditor.instances.insertText(value);
  }
```

I am getting an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'instances' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use with `{static: false}`:

```
@ViewChild("editor", { static: false }) myEditor: any;
```

`false` means that it resolves [after change detection](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description).

UPDATE:

You need to use the same name in `.ts` and `.html` (name with `#` sign) files:

HTML:

```
<ck-editor name="editor" #myEditor [(ngModel)]="editorValue" 
     skin="moono-lisa" language="en" [fullPage]="true"></ck-editor>
```

TypeScript:

```
 @ViewChild("myEditor", { static: false }) myEditor: any;
```

and use it like this:

```
this.myEditor.instance.insertText(value);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I tried not working for me  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdp7d1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts still i am getting the same error

Comment: Now I am getting different error Cannot read property 'insertText' of undefined

Comment: @techie18 I am sorry, I do not know. Maybe it is better to see in docs.

Comment: I am also trying to do that in Ckeditor 5 but its not working for me

Comment: @techie18 It is better to ask a new question as it is good practice to have one question per post.

Comment: yes, I asked @StepUp but no reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100779/insert-the-text-in-editor-is-not-working-ckeditor-5-with-angular-7